# Snowflake Snowspark showing SnowparkSQLException:SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 13 invalid identifier 'FIRST_NAME' when querying

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake called as CUSTOMERS in snowflake. It has the following columns:
[image]

I am trying to query the first_name and the last_name columns from it using snowspark. Following is the code that I am trying:

```
def snowpark_session_create():
connection_params = {
    'account':'****************',
    'user':'******************',
    'password':'*************',
    'role':'*********************',
    'warehouse':'***********'
}
session = Session.builder.configs(connection_params).create()
return session

demo_session = snowpark_session_create()
# point session to a specific database and schema
demo_session.use_database('EXERCISE_DB')
demo_session.use_schema('PUBLIC')

# getting a specific table
df = demo_session.table("CUSTOMERS")

df2 = df.select('ID', "first_name", "last_name")
df2.show()
```

But I get this error

```
SnowparkSQLException: (1304): 01abc07b-0001-9954-001e-108700050072: 000904 (42000): SQL 
compilation error: error line 1 at position 13
invalid identifier 'FIRST_NAME'
```

I have tried different ways, like using "(double quoted strings) and using `` to enclose the column names but none of them have solved this. I even checked for a case difference but that too hasnt solved the issue.

How do I solve this error?

Comment: try this: ```df2 = df.select('ID', '"first_name"', '"last_name"')```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Does snowflake auto capitalize the column names in the backend? Im new to it so i do not have any knowledge of this.

Comment: Yes, I will post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to my comment. The behavior is explained in the [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax).

If an object, e.g. table or column was created using double-quotes using different from "all capitals" case, in the future all references in the code to this object must be done using double-quotes, otherwise it will be capitalized.

In SQL it will be just double quotes, in Python it will be another couple of quotes around the identifier, to make sure that the proper name with double quotes will be passed to Snowflake.

Therefore, the correct syntax will be as follows:

```python
df2 = df.select('ID', '"first_name"', '"last_name"')
```

that makes it an equivalent of the following query:

```sql
select ID, "first_name", "last_name" from my_table
```

Note: different programming languages might have different ways how to handle passing a string that includes double quotes in order to keep them as a part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @aek I found the solution. For anyone wondering, the right way, as pointed out by him would be:

```
df2 = df.select('ID', '"first_name"', '"last_name"')
```